# Asp.Net-MVC3 - how to play uploaded video on page using video url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want play flash video on my page using video url for eg. i have a text box for submitting video URL (any youtube, vimeo, hulu video url) after submitting video play on same page.

my code is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("url")
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Video Url" />
    <br /> 
}

    <div id="frame">
    <iframe id="testIframe" width="420" height="315" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '';
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            if ($('#url').val() != '') {
                $("#testIframe").attr("src", $('#url').val());

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: SO is for helping with specific coding problems. Your question could be solved by a simple Google search.

Comment: i am not getting perfect solution i am new on asp.net-mvc and jquery

Comment: If you are not getting a perfect solution, it is not a problem. You must have tried something already. Experimented with some code. Done some research on your behalf. Haven't you? Even if it is not perfect you could share it with us and we will be happy to look at it and improve it. But you should absolutely not expect someone doing the job for you without showing any efforts on your side. At least not on Stack Overflow. At its current state chances are that your question will be closed.

Comment: how to convert video url to embedded video src

Answer (score 0):

video embed code have the option to set it autoplay so you have to check the code of every provider.
You can check this example if can't find: 
http://videoplayer.codeplex.com/